# Как нажать кнопку на интернет-странице

Tags: delphi, сеть

Как ее можно найти в `html` ( через атрибуты или айдишники) и нажать. Что для этого нужно? пробовал через `idwebbrowser`, но это не то, браузерная страница не нужна

Comment: "Ваша" кнопка по нажатию что-то делает. Или запускается javascript, или отправляются данные Post/get запросом. Всем этим заведует движок браузера. Сам html - это просто структурированный текстовый файл, сам по себе он ничего не умеет. Если вам действительно нужно действие "нажать на кнопку", то без TWebBrowser или аналогов - не обойтись. А вот если же вам нужно выполнить какие-то действия, происходящие при нажатии - то тут возможны варианты.

Comment: спасибо, натолкнули на идею...Вопрос решен.